# Android - NDK The LOCAL_SRC_FILES for a prebuilt library should only contain one item

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, static-libraries, android.mk

I use a c++ library on my app. The library generates an `.a` file in previous version. My Android.mk file is below:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libmylib
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := path-to/libmylib.a
else
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := path-to/libmylib.a
endif
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
.......


LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += mylib
.......
```

But now, I build it and it generates 3 `.so` files.

How can I add an module that includes multiple `.so` sources?

Below settings doesn't compile.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libmylib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := path-to/libvmylib_shared.so \  path-to/libvmylib_base.so  \ path-to/libvmylib_cr.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
.....

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += mylib
```

The error is here:

> The LOCAL_SRC_FILES for a prebuilt library should only contain one
>   item

Comment: Split it into three modules, then add all three to your `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES`.

Answer (score 4):

One library is one module. You need to make multiple modules.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libvmylib_shared
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := path-to/libvmylib_shared.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libvmylib_base
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := path-to/libvmylib_base.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libvmylib_cr
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := path-to/libvmylib_cr.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

...

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libvmylib_shared libvmylib_base libvmylib_cr
```

Answer (score 0):

If your 'if' is to define different abi source, try:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libmylib.a
```